# Haskell Data Type Instance as operator

Tags: haskell, concatenation, instance

I have recieved a exercice to learn about data types in haskell and I can't figure out how to solve this one.

They got me a data like : `data CatLista a = Nil | Unit a| Conc (CatLista a) (CatLista a) deriving Eq`
and I need to make the data types become: Nil -> [] , Unit x -> [x] , Conc -> same operator as (++)

So if you run `Conc (Unit 9)(Conc (Unit 5) (Unit 3)) == Conc (Conc (Unit 9) (Unit 5))(Conc (Unit 3) Nil)`  should give true and `Conc (Unit 9)(Unit 3) == Conc (Unit 3) (Unit 9)` should give false.

I already tried instancing the show class like this:

```
instance Show a => Show (CatLista a) where
    show a = case a of
        Nil -> []
        Unit x -> "[" ++ show x ++ "]"
        Conc Nil dos -> show dos
        Conc uno Nil -> show uno 
        Conc uno dos -> "[" + show uno ++ "," ++ show dos ++ "]"
```

I'm quite new to haskell so I may not know some basics, because I can't understand why if I run it (beeing `Conc uno dos -> show uno ++ show dos`) with the same command as bellow `Conc (Unit 9)(Conc (Unit 5) (Unit 3)) == Conc (Conc (Unit 9) (Unit 5))(Conc (Unit 3) Nil)` it still returns False even tough they both return the same [9][5][3] with my show instance.

**EDIT**

Thanks to you I made it, it know returns correctly the values like intended with this code:

```
toLista :: Eq a => CatLista a -> [a]
toLista Nil = []
toLista (Unit x) = [x]
toLista (Conc a b) 
                    | a == Nil = toLista b 
                    | b == Nil = toLista a
                    | otherwise = (++) (toLista a) (toLista b)

instance (Show a,(Eq a)) => Show (CatLista a) where 
    show a= show (toLista a)
```

But still I dont know why if I try the same comparation it still returns False, even tough I get returned the same [9,5,3].

This is probably due to my lack of knowledge in Haskell, sorry about that.

Comment: Two lists having the same string presentation does not mean the two objects are equivalent. You will need to define your own instance of `Eq` for the `CatLista`.

Comment: Define `toList :: CatLista a -> [a]` first, then the `Show` instance is a trivial composition of `toList` and `show` for lists.

Comment: Your definition assumes that the string representation of a `Conc` value is the concatenation of the string representations of the two halves, rather than just the *elements* of the two halves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two values are not equivalent if these produce the same `String` when calling `show` on these. The [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) function is implemented by the [**`Eq`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq). You thus need to implement the `instance` of `Eq` for your `CatLista` yourself.

The default implementation for `Eq`, if you use `deriving Eq` is that two values are the same if they have the same data constructor, and the parameters are elementwise equivalent by calling `(==)` on these.

You thus can implement the instance for `Eq` yourself with:

```
data CatLista a = Nil | Unit a| Conc (CatLista a) (CatLista a) -- ← no deriving Eq

instance Eq a => Eq (CatLista a) where
    ca == cb = toLista ca == toLista cb
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One little question about your answer with you could help me: When you do `ca == cb = toLista ca == toLista cb` you are meaning that, two random CatLista (ca and cb) are equal when their representation are equal (`toLista ca == toLista cb`) ? Thanks again

Comment: @AnderCarrera: `toLista ca` converts a `CataLista` to a list, so the two are equivalent if these are equivalent as list. This function thus *not* says that two `CataLista`s are equivalent if they have the same `show`, although since you both define it in terms of `toLista` that will be the case here.

Answer (score 4):

Because you include `deriving Eq` in the data declaration, you're telling the compiler to generate a default equality method. The compiler cannot read your mind and know that you intend to represent lists via concatenation of sublists.

**You** know you intend `Conc [1, 2] [3]` to represent the same list as `Conc [1] [2, 3]`<sup>1</sup>; either should be regarded as representing `[1, 2, 3]`. The compiler does **not** know this. The generated equality method sees that in one case we have `[1, 2]` in the first field of the `Conc` constructor, and in the other case we have `[1]`. Those two things aren't equal, so the default equality method says that the whole structure is not equal either.

To avoid that, stop messing around with the `Show` instance. `Show` is for converting a `CatList` to a `String` of code that would build it. It has nothing to do with testing equality. There's no possible way you can change the outcome of `==` by defining a `Show` instance.

You need to remove `deriving Eq` from the data declaration. That will mean the compiler doesn't generate a default equality method, so you can write your own one that does something different (compares whether two `CatList`s **represent the same list** rather than comparing whether they **have the same structure**).

---

<sup>1</sup> I am abusing notation here to write the sublists using bracket syntax; this is *not* valid code, I'm just trying to make the difference in sub-structure more easily visible.